# react-native ios "Could not connect to development server" and "__fbBatchedBridge is undefined" errors

Tags: ios, react-native

## react-native ios "Could not connect to development server" and "__fbBatchedBridge is undefined" errors

I'm freshman in react-native. I tried deploy a "hello world" app according to official documents. But failed.

Here what i try:

- install all dependencies according to official site
- init my local project using command `react-native init HelloWorld` (At first my project name is `try`, but it's a reserved keyword, so I changed to `HelloWorld`)
- install all node_modues using `npm install`
- try to run my project using command `react-native run-ios`

my environments are:

- osx `10.10.5`
- watchman `4.5`
- xcode `7.2.1`
- react-native-cli `1.0.0`
- react-native `0.28.0`
- react `15.1.0`

After running command `react-native run-ios`, i got this red background error:

> Cound not connect to development server.
>
> Ensue the folloing:
>
> - Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
> - Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
>
> URL: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform-ios&dev=true

I searched google, and found it is a common problem mainly due to osx 9.0 security policy.

I read through the [github issue: cound not connect to development server](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/304) and check and modify my project:

- make sure `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `Info.plist` setting is ok.

  ```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  ```
- tried change `jsCodeLocation` in `AppDelegate.m` from `localhost` to `my local network ip` (In fact, i can visit the jsCodeLocation[localhost] in my chrome browser, but i changed my ip according to the github issue anyway, just try)

When i retry the command "react-native run-ios", the connect error disappeared, but come with another error "__fbBatchedBridge is undefined"

> Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined
>
> RCTFatal + 104
>   ...

I read through the github issue: `github->facebook/react-native/issues/6282`, and try commenting out the following lines `github->facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/react-native-xcode.sh#L15-L18`

```
#    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then        
#      echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"      
#      exit 0;      
#    fi
```

But nothing happened. Anybody can help? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running your app from XCode directly?

Comment: yes, i tried, but the result is the same with command "react-native run-ios"

Comment: Are you trying to run it on a device or a simulator?

Comment: on simulator 9.2 and real device 9.2.1, both have the problem, i will try more simulator tonight

Answer (score 0):

The project name you've chosen `try` is a reserved word in javascript. This will result in problems from the beginning. For example it will generate a class name of `try` as follows:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class try extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This will result in errors and unpredictability. Try to generate a new react native application using something like `MyApp` and give it another go.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, you are very careful, i come with this problem at first, but fixed that later myself ( i'm a front engineer). So, it's not this reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

The reason is simple and silly,

Just add `localhost 127.0.0.1` in hosts and the problem will disappear.